# Evaluate $\int_{0}^1 \int_{0}^1 \int_{0}^1 \frac{1}{x^2+y^2+z^2}dxdydz$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

I am trying to evaluate the following integral:
$$I =\int_{0}^1 \int_{0}^1 \int_{0}^1 \frac{1}{x^2+y^2+z^2}dxdydz.$$

Here is my trial. By using spherical coordinate, let 
$x = r\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi), y = r\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi), z = r\cos(\phi).$
Then one can write $I$ as
$$ I = \int_{\Omega} \frac{1}{r^2} r^2\sin(\theta)drd\theta d\phi
= \int_{\Omega} \sin(\theta)drd\theta d\phi$$
where $\Omega$ is something I can't figure out...
Here $\Omega$ is
$$ \Omega = \{(r,\theta,\phi) : 0\le x,y,z \le 1\}.$$
Since $0\le z=r\cos(\phi) \le1$, we have
$$ 0 \le \arccos(1/r) \le \phi \le \pi/2. $$
Since $0\le y=r\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi) \le 1$, we have
$$ 0 \le \theta \le \arcsin(1/(r\cos(\phi)).$$
But I don't see how such classification help in evaluating $I$.

Any suggestions/comments/answers will be very appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would help to notice that the $r^2$ terms cancel in the spherical integral.

Comment: @majormaki Thanks for your comment. I was aware of this cancellation but it didn't help to me go further.

Comment: Well then, integrate $\sin(\theta)$ over $\Omega$: find the bounds. The integrand does not depend on the angular variables so the answer will be a multiple of $-\cos(\theta)$.

Comment: I would say you can divide the cube into 3 equal regions and by the symmetry of the function, the integral is the same over all three.  Cut the box along the lines $x = y, y = z, x = 0, z = 1$  Even then, the integral seems to get messy.

Comment: The integral is equal to $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\pi^{3/2}}{4t^2}\operatorname{erf}^3 (t)\,dt, $$ though I am not sure whether it will ever help.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thanks for your comment. This helps a bit as a starting. Could you provide me a reference for this?

Comment: @SangchulLee: the integral boils down to a fashionable dilogarithmic integral.

Comment: This is a consequence of an easy transformation $$ \frac{1}{x^2+y^2+z^2} = \int_{0}^{\infty} 2t e^{-(x^2+y^2+z^2)t^2} \, dt, $$ but Jack D'Aurizio's answer tells that an earnest computation seems to work best.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I might have a better idea than parametrizing a cube in spherical coordinates (*ugh*), which is to further exploit symmetry:
$$ \mathcal{J}=\iiint_{(-1,1)^3}\frac{d\mu}{x^2+y^2+z^2}=8\iiint_{(0,1)^3}\frac{d\mu}{x^2+y^2+z^2}=48\iiint_{0\leq z\leq y\leq x\leq 1}\frac{d\mu}{x^2+y^2+z^2} $$
Now the substitution $z=yc, dz=y\,dc$ turns the RHS into
$$ 48\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{y}{x^2+y^2+c^2 y^2}\,dc  \,dy\,dx $$
and the substitution $y=xb, dy=x\,db$ turns the last integral into
$$ 48\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^2 b}{x^2+b^2 x^2+c^2 b^2 x^2}\,dc  \,db\,dx = 48\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{ b}{1+b^2+c^2 b^2}\,dc  \,db$$
or
$$ 24\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(2+c^2)}{1+c^2}\,dc=24\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\log(2+\tan^2\theta)d\theta  $$
which is an integral in a single-variable, requiring the [dilogarithms](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html) machinery to be computed in closed form. Numerically, $\mathcal{J}\approx\frac{353}{23}$. In explicit terms

$$ \mathcal{J}=24\left[\text{Im}\,\text{Li}_2((3-2\sqrt{2})i)-G+\frac{\pi}{4}\log(3+2\sqrt{2})\right]$$
where $G$ is Catalan's constant.

Comment: Sometimes the good old way works best! :) (+1)

Comment: I hope this is not a stupid question, but when one make the substitution say: x=ys can we choose freely which way to differentiate(dx=yds but also dx=sdy)?

Comment: @Zacky: of course not, the change of variables are chosen in such a way that $0\leq z\leq y\leq x \leq 1$ is mapped back into a cube of the $(0,1)^3$ kind. For instance since $y$ ranges from $0$ to $x$ I chose to set $y=xb, dy=x\,db$, in such a way that $b$ ranges over $(0,1)$.

Comment: What a great answer! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

Here is another way: Let $\mathbf{F}$ be defined by

$$ \mathbf{F} = \left( \frac{x}{x^2+y^2+z^2}, \frac{y}{x^2+y^2+z^2}, \frac{z}{x^2+y^2+z^2} \right). $$

Then it is easy to check that $\operatorname{div}\mathbf{F} = \frac{1}{x^2+y^2+z^2}$. So if $I$ denotes the integral in question, then by the divergence theorem<sup>1)</sup> we get

$$ 8I
= \int_{[-1, 1]^3} \operatorname{div}\mathbf{F} \, dV
= \int_{\partial [-1, 1]^3} \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{n} \, dA. $$

Again by symmetry,

$$ 8I
= 6 \int_{\{1\}\times[-1,1]^2} \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{e}_1 \, dydz
= 24 \int_{[0,1]^2} \frac{dydz}{1+y^2+z^2}.$$

Applying the polar coordinate change, we have

$$ \int_{[0,1]^2} \frac{dydz}{1+y^2+z^2}
= \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \int_{0}^{\sec\theta} \frac{2r}{1+r^2} \, drd\theta
= \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \log(1 + \sec^2\theta) \, d\theta,$$

which leads to the same integral as in **Jack D'Aurizio**'s answer

$$ I = 3\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \log(2 + \tan^2\theta) \, d\theta. $$

---

1) It can be easily shown, by excising a small ball around $0$ and letting the radius zero, that the singularity of $\mathbf{F}$ at $0$ poses no issue.

Comment: Another good approach. Thanks for your answer. One quick follow up question. Do you think this approach has a potential generalization? That is, $$I_n = \int_{[0,1]^n} \frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}d\mu_n.$$ I tried to mimic this approach but I stuck on computing $$\int_{[0,1]^{n-1}} \frac{d\mu_{n-1}}{1+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x_i^2}.$$ Using Jack D'Aurizio approaches, this ends up with computing $$ \frac{1}{n-2}\int_{[0,1]^{n-1}} \frac{\prod_{i=1}^{n-2}w_i^i}{1+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\prod_{j=1}^i w_{n-j}^2}d\omega_{n-1}.$$